# Informix IfmxStatement.getSerial() to PostgreSQL substitute

Tags: database, postgresql, informix

Could you help me, because I have a problem?  My task is to port a database from Informix to PostgreSQL, but someone use IfmxStatement method getSerial(), and I can't find any substitute for it in PostgreSQL.

```
Integer serial = new Integer(((IfmxStatement) stmt.getSerial());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`getGeneratedKeys()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#getGeneratedKeys%28%29) which is part of JDBC

```
stmt.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO ...", Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
// retrieve the auto generated key/keys
ResultSet rs = stmt.getGeneratedKeys();
if (rs.next())
    {
    int serial = rs.getInt(1);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Thank you, this is my solution.

```
int serial=0;
      ResultSet rs = null;
      String query="SELECT nextval('id_seq');"; 
      try   
      {
         rs=stmt.executeQuery(query);
         if (rs.next())
            {
            serial = rs.getInt(1);
            }
         setId(serial);
```